# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError Displayed After Tapping Button Twice

Tags: java, android

I have two ImageButtons on one activity that work completely fine when pressed, one makes a call while the other opens up the sms text messaging app. I also have a 'skip' Button at the bottom of the activity where users can go back to their profile page, however, one I tap on the button once in simulator nothing happens and when I press it twice I receive this error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. I set all my buttons up the same way so I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error.

I did have the button pressed within its own method, but then switched and put it in the onCreate. But here's the code for my button:

```
Button _skipButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.skipButton);

        _skipButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MessageOrCallActivity.this, MyActivity.class));
        }
});
```

Additionally, here's the error printed within the logs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 499046412 byte allocation with 1060954 free bytes and 62MB until OOM
                                                                             at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                                                                             at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                                                                             at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
                                                                             at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
                                                                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                                                                             at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
                                                                             at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:58)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:54)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:95)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:992)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
                                                                             at com.example.myApp.myApp.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:14)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Anyone know whats going on? I saw several post where this occurred while working with an array, but I have no arrays currently for this activity or the one I'm trying to transition to. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any large images in your project being reference by XML layouts?

Comment: Oh, I think it may be due to the large ImageView thats on the activity that I'm trying to transition to. Other than that, there isn't anything besides two ImageButtons and a regular Button that I'm trying to transition from.

Comment: Your error message says you tried to allocate a 499-MB Bitmap. The callstack indicates that it happens as part of loading a Drawable resource for an ImageView while inflating some layout. So yeah it's probably your large ImageView -- or rather, your very large image contained in that view.

Comment: Yup, ImageView on the other activity was the problem. I redirected the button to go to another activity and it popped up fine. So I just have to figure out now how to resize the bitmap. Thanks!